# How to make SEO friendly URL for my custom pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-pages

I am designing and development a site using WordPress the problem is that i want to set SEO friendly URL for my custom pages and i don't know how to change in WordPress.

I have this URL currently working on a site

http://jetrequest.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner

I want this URL

http://jetrequest.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/VIP-Airliner

Comment: And really none of the millions of explanations about exactly this topic here on SO and out on google helped you to manage your taks? _Why not?_ What is so different in your case?

Comment: I have  never changed any thing in Wordpress using .htaccess file

Comment: Ok, sure, got that. Though I am not certain why you mention that. But anyway, that is not meant to be an answer to the question in my last comment, is it?

Comment: :) answer please..

Comment: Sorry, no. What I try to express it: you are expected to do research and solve your task yourself. We are only here to help with details you cannot find out yourself. This is _not_ a place to dump your task and say "do it for me", we are _not_ a free coding service. For that please hire a (payed) programmer. You are expected to code yourself, to know your tools and to be able to answer to questions. You appear to not be concerned with all that...

Answer (score 0):

On your sites WordPress dashboard hover over the settings tab (located in the left sidebar) and then click "permalinks" it will take you to a new page, choose the option "post name" and click save.

Comment: already set post name on that page i am getting this by id $_GET['id']

Comment: Try doing it through the WordPress dashboard and setting the permalink as the post name like I said... This should fix the issue.